# Is it any restriction to use AND condition in query of postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query which returns a wrong answer. Wrong answer in the sense that I know of no data in the table that satisfy the condition, but it returns data.

Below I pasted my query. Please let me know if any mistake I made.

```
   SELECT DISTINCT ON (checkup_id) behavior_checkup_key, bcf.behavior_key, checkup_id, compliance, counter, 
       bcf.date_key, org_unit_history_key, org_unit_key, performed_by_key, 
       subject_key , view_analytics.bdn.process_name
  FROM view_analytics.behavior_checkup_fact bcf
  JOIN view_analytics.behavior_dimension bdn  ON bcf.behavior_key = bdn.behavior_key  
  JOIN view_analytics.date_dimension ddn  ON bcf.date_key = ddn.date_key
  WHERE bcf.performed_by_key = 336 AND 
        bcf.org_unit_key = 11 AND
        bdn.process_name = 'Test_Process_For_testing'  AND 
        ddn.month_name = 'May' AND 
        ddn.year = 2014;
```

Above query returns number of rows based on the `WHERE` condition. I also use `DISTINCT` on a column `checkup_id`. I am using PostgreSQL.

Is it any restriction to use an `AND` condition in PostgreSQL? 
In this query I want to emphasize this condition: `date_dimension.month_name = 'May' AND date_dimension.year = 2014;`. I know there is no data in that year and month, but the query returns data.

Do I need any priority logic to write the `AND` condition in the query?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: PostgreSql @jarlh ,

Comment: The issue may not be with the WHERE clause but with the FROM clause. 
Since you have listed many tables, separated by commas, it defaults to an inner join.

Comment: @sjgp okay i will explore that `FROM` and let u know

Comment: @sjgp A cross join if no join condition is enforced.

Answer (score 2):

I re-wrote your query with putting the JOINs associations together:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (checkup_id) behavior_checkup_key, bcf.behavior_key, checkup_id, compliance, counter, 
       bcf.date_key, org_unit_history_key, org_unit_key, performed_by_key, 
       subject_key , view_analytics.bd.process_name
  FROM view_analytics.behavior_checkup_fact bcf
  JOIN view_analytics.behavior_dimension bd ON bcf.behavior_key = bd.behavior_key
  JOIN view_analytics.date_dimension -- !!!! Missing: ON dd.column = bcf.column or bdn.column
  WHERE performed_by_key = 336 AND 
        org_unit_key = 11 AND
        bd.process_name = 'Test_Process_For_testing'  AND 
        dd.month_name = 'May' AND 
        dd.year = 2014;
```

You are missing an `ON` clause on the `view_analytics.date_dimension` table so it is associating unexpected rows

Comment: thanks , if run the above ur query i m getting error like `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 7:   WHERE performed_by_key = 336 AND 
          ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: syntax error at or near "WHERE"
SQL state: 42601
Character: 406` @Gab

Comment: is that am i miss any thing in that query @Gab

Comment: you are missing ` Missing: ON dd.column = bcf.column or bdn.column` in the last JOIN as I mentionned in my answer, you need to fix that

Comment: thanks @Gab , i added that ON condition to my query but now show the error on before `FROM` condition `**view_analytics**.bdn.process_name`.

Comment: `SELECT *** view_analytics.bdn.process_name ---!!! this line
  FROM view_analytics.behavior_checkup_fact bcf
  JOIN view_analytics.behavior_dimension bdn  ON bcf.behavior_key = bdn.behavior_key  
  JOIN view_analytics.date_dimension ddn  ON bcf.date_key = ddn.date_key
  WHERE bcf.performed_by_key = 336 AND 
        bcf.org_unit_key = 11 AND
        bdn.process_name = 'Test_Process_For_testing'  AND 
        ddn.month_name = 'May' AND 
        ddn.year = 2014;` @Gab

Comment: I changed above query in my question fr your reference

Comment: i pasted my latest query with `ON` date condition , in that query when I remove the `, view_analytics.bdn.process_name` before `FROM` . Its shown the correct answer but with `view_analytics.bdn.process_name` this. Got an error bro..,like

Comment: `ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "behavior_dimension"
LINE 3:        subject_key , view_analytics.behavior_dimension.proce...
                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "bdn".
********** Error **********

ERROR: invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "behavior_dimension"
SQL state: 42P01
Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the table alias "bdn".
Character: 204`

Comment: Corrected my answer, I put `bdn` instead of `bd` by accident

Comment: thanks , now its working .also i need to know why i am not use many `and` conditions with `where` . I knew i need to google it , but i am not understanding ..,

Comment: when i was google , why should i go for `JOIN` and `ON` concept ., i am totally new to the query related work ., how do i need to improve my skills in query related concepts .., like you .., also please bear with my english , also i post my skpe id `sureshanand.s` .if u wnt to talk to me plz snd a request, but i need yu like guys to talk imprve my progrmming skils

Comment: thanks, please see the above two comments i didnt mentioned last day above thats why u may not recieved notification my comment yet i think so .., @Gab

Comment: `JOIN ... ON table1.column = table2.column` is the same as doing `... WHERE table1.column = table2.column`. Using `ON` makes the relationship between tables much easier to read and it will be easier to maintain the queries in the future.

Comment: If I answered your question, please approve my answer on stack overflow, it would help. thanks!